# Crop page before CSS footer

Tags: html, css

This question may be already answered in Stackoverflow. But I appreciate if someone can provide me a solution.

I'm trying to create PDF with CSS and HTML. I have added a footer to it.

```
@page {
       @bottom-left {content: element(footer);}
       size:A4 portrait;
       margin-left: 0;
       margin-right: 0;
       margin-top: 0;
}

div.footer {
            display: block;
            position: running(footer);
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 5;
           }

 <div class="footer" style="padding-left: 1.7cm;">
      MY FOOTER
</div>
```

This renders footer correctly but page content also overlaps on it. How do i avoid overlapping and display overflow content on the next page ?

[image]

Comment: what language are you using to generate the PDF? HTML and CSS can not generate PDF's.

Comment: @Syfer Its a Visualforce page (Salesforce)

Comment: you can also see this happen in a print preview. `fixed` position in a paged medium means that it should show up on every page.

Comment: @guest Thanks. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the fixed position from Footer and added margin bottom to page

```
@page {
       @bottom-left {content: element(footer);}
       size:A4 portrait;
       margin: 0 0 5cm 0;
    }

div.footer {
             display: block;
             position: running(footer);
             z-index: 5;
            }
```